# Core Data Delete Objects with the same name

Tags: ios, swift, object, core-data

```
//taken from Core Data    
var items:NSMutableArray = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 1","Item 3"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         if(editingStyle == .Delete){
            let itemName = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
            //delete all rows in core data with this item name
         }
    }
```

How to delete all rows in Core Data which have field name "itemName" ?

Comment: I don't know the code which I have to execute to delete all objects with name = itemName ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `NSFetchRequest` and set an `NSPredicate` with your item name. Executing this fetch request gives you an array of all `NSManagedObjects` with that predicate.

Then iterate over that array and call the `NSManagedObjectContext`'s method `deleteObject(object)`

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "yourEntityName")
fetchRequest.includesSubentities = false
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == '\(itemName)'")

var error: NSError?

// moc is your NSManagedObjectContext here
items = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)!

for item in items {
    moc.deleteObject(item)
}
```

Comment: I remember reading that we still had to use %@ with the predicate format string, for Objective-C and Swift

Comment: Better: `NSPredicate(format:"name == %@", itemName)`. Otherwise you'll have problems if the item name contains any special characters such as quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  if let index = find(items, items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))

              {
                 items.removeAtIndex(index)

              }
```